# How can i extend the background image in my app to show in the footer and in the navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

My code looks like this:

```
<template>
    <v-app>
      <AppBar></AppBar>
      <v-main>
        <router-view></router-view>
      </v-main>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

`v-app` is overriding the footer and the navbar. So the footer and the navbar have a solid color and my background has an image. I want the image to cover it all.

Comment: `color="transparent"` should work on both the bar and footer.

Comment: The problem is that i can't select the v-app component therefore i can't set the background for the whole layout. If i put color='transparent' it doesn't do anything because the image doesn't show behind the bar and the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved it, i had to add #app in style.